# Why when I use API in every Flutter my Emulator paused?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-runtime

Why when I use the API in any Flutter project, the application stops after running the application with the Emulator
?

I Should click the continue button for see result

but, When I run with Chrome or Edge, I don't have this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just uncheck the **Uncaught Exceptions**

[image]

Comment: why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Uncaught Exceptions" option in your debug panel control

Comment: Where is it? please tell more about this